# Looking to have a copy of another database that automatically updates and has a few additional columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-replication

I'm very new to database/server management. I'm working with a database that I can't add any columns to since it interfaces directly with another piece of software and therefore must stay in a very specific format. However, I'd like to be able to add DateCreated, and CreatedBy columns to the tables in this database to setup some automatic email updates when new entries are made. To do this, I thought I might be able to keep a copy of the original database that automatically updates when changes are made to the original and simply add the  additional columns to the copy. I'm working in Microsoft SQL 2017. If anyone could provide any guidance on the best way to accomplish this, your help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Would you consider just creating another table with the new columns and have it point to the target table?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some ideas on making this a better question. As it sits right now it is just too vague.

Comment: Create a replica data base which is refreshed every night if your purpose is analytical, or you may think about real time replication using something like debezium https://debezium.io/

Comment: You need to understand exactly what you can and can't do to this database. Can you add triggers? Can you turn on CDC (change data capture?)

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I'm willing to try adding triggers and possibly CDC with my database, I just don't want to add any tables or add any columns to existing tables. Would it be possible to setup triggers on my database to simply add the DateCreated and CreatedBy columns to a table in another database? Not sure if this would be preferable to using CDC.

Comment: CDC creates a lot of objects in your database so you can't use that. Triggers writing logs to tables is a manual but proven solution. I'm not aware of any issues with a trigger writing to a different database. Except that cross database doesn't work in Azure, if that's a future option. Typically your log table would just have three columns: primary key, datecreated, dateupdated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a table extension that consists of the additional columns + the key value from the original table. Each row in Table 1 should have 1 or 0 rows in Table 2. Use a trigger on Table 1 to insert a row in Table 2 on Insert or Update.